# Allocate space for struct pointer member through constructor

Tags: c, oop, malloc

I want to use structs like objects in C.

Suppose I have the following:

```
typedef struct {
    /* ... */
    size_t *pages_len;
} book;
```

And I use the following method to construct it:

```
int book_init(/* some args... */, book * b) {
    /* do some validation */
    /* compute the number of pages n_pages */
    b->pages_len = (size_t*) calloc(n_pages, sizeof(size_t));
    /* compute pages_len based on some args */
    return 0;
}
```

Then I construct an object like this:

```
book *my_book = (book*)malloc(sizeof(my_book));
if (book_init(/* some args */, my_book) == 0) {
    /* do something */
}
```

And I destroy my object like: `book_destroy(book *b)` where I `free(b->pages_len)`.

Is this correct or am I missing something? I can't show the original code but I am having trouble:

1. Accessing `b->pages_len` after the init method.
2. Destroying the object. I am having memory corruption.

As requested, a minimal reproducible example:

```
/* book.h */
#ifndef BOOK_HEADER_
#define BOOK_HEADER_
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct
{
  size_t pages_count;
  size_t *pages_len;
} * book;

int book_create (book b);
#endif /* BOOK_HEADER_ */
```

```
/* book.c */
#include "book"

int
book_create (book b)
{
  b->pages_len = calloc (3, sizeof (b->pages_len));
  b->pages_len[2] = 20;
  return 0;
}
```

```
/* test.c */
#include "book.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  book my_book = (book)malloc (sizeof (book));
  int r = book_create (my_book);
  printf ("\n%lu\n", my_book->pages_len[2]);
  free (my_book->pages_len);
  free (my_book);
}
```

What I get from my memory leak detector is that `free(my_book)` gives a `Memory corruption (written out of bounds?)` error. One thing that fixed this error was changing the order of `pages_count` and `pages_len` but I don't know why.

I just typed the above example, so if there is any typo or syntactic error, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The `sizeof(b->pages_len)` in your `calloc` call smells dangerous. It will be the size of a pointer and, if pointers are smaller than `size_t` then you'll have issues.

Comment: Note that since `b->pages_len` is a pointer, `sizeof(b->pages_len)` is the size of that pointer. Perhaps you meant `sizeof(*b->pages_len)` to get the size of each element?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess that's safe as it's evaluated at compile-time; but it *looks* like de-referencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: That might be. To eliminate any smell and confusion I will replace it with sizeof(size_t).

Comment: I am still having trouble accessing book->pages_len after my init and am having memory corruption when freeing book->pages_len.

Comment: Even if it might be hard, please try to create a [mcve] to show us. At least show the important parts of the `book_init` and `book_destroy` functions, as well as how you use the structure and the `pages_len` member. And please elaborate on the "having trouble" part., What happens when you try to access the `pages_len` member? What is supposed to happen? Do you get build errors? Run-time errors or crashes? Unexpected results? Except for the build errors, have you tried using a debugger to catch the crash or step through the code to see what really happens?

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your `#include "book"` should be `book.h`, and you need `<stdlib.h>` in the two .c files and `<stdio.h>` in `test.c`  After that it compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`book my_book = malloc(sizeof(book))` is wrong.  Note that the type of `book` is pointer to your struct, but you want to allocate enough space for the struct itself.  So as the code stands, you will need to write `malloc(sizeof(*my_book))`.

However, using `typedef` to define a name for a pointer is usually bad style; it leads to confusion, and you will find it very awkward that your struct type doesn't have a name.  A better way to write this would just be as

```
struct book
{
  size_t pages_count;
  size_t *pages_len;
};

struct book *my_book = malloc(sizeof(*my_book));
```

In this case `malloc(sizeof(struct book))` would also work, but will become broken if you ever change the type of `my_book`.

It's often suggested that you not typedef away the `struct`, and just keep calling it `struct book` everywhere, because it's usually good to remember what kind of object you are working with.  But if you must, you can still do `typedef struct book book;` afterwards.  As mentioned, I would **not** recommend `typedef struct book *book;`.

Casting the result of `malloc` should never be necessary in C.  You presumably included it because you got a warning about the return type of `malloc`, but the correct fix is to include the standard header `<stdlib.h>`.  Indeed, this is precisely the reason why people usually recommend that you do *not* cast the result of `malloc`, because it can silence warnings that indicate a real bug.  See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for much more on this topic.

You also need `<stdio.h>` in `test.c`.

Also, `create_book` should return a value (but this is not the cause of your crash, since you never use it).

It is not surprising that rearranging the struct members made the bug appear to go away.  What probably happened is something like this.  On a typical 64-bit system, `size_t` and pointers are each 8 bytes.  So you had allocated 8 bytes for your struct, when its size is actually 16.  But you only actually wrote to the `pages_len` member.  So if `pages_len` is the first member of the struct, and you never write to the `pages_count` member, you are only writing within the 8 bytes you allocated, and nothing goes wrong.  Of course, the code was still broken, and as soon as you added any code that used the `pages_count` member, or added or rearranged any members of your struct, the bug would be back.

But in general, blindly changing things until a bug goes away is an extremely bad idea when programming in C.  You may very easily do something that only *masks* the bug and makes it harder to find.  There's no substitute for actually understanding what is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately ```sizeof(book)``` still gives the same error. I forgot to return something in the MRE thanks. The casting is because of compiler warnings.

Comment: Also do you why changing the order of the struct members avoid the error?

Comment: I've made all of your changes and I still get the same error.

Comment: @TertulianoMáximoAfonso: Please show your new code.  There are several other changes you would have needed to make to adapt the rest of your code to the type definitions I suggested; I left those to you, but there could be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(my_book))` is still wrong!  I suggested two options and this is neither of them.  Pay attention to the type of the thing you put inside `sizeof`:  you have a pointer, not a `struct book`.  Also you still do not have `<stdlib.h>` or `<stdio.h>` included.

Comment: @TertulianoMáximoAfonso: And `b->pages_len = calloc (3, sizeof (b->pages_len));` is also wrong for exactly the same reason: the type of `b->pages_len` is a pointer, not `size_t`.  Make it `sizeof(*(b->pages_len))` or `sizeof(size_t)`.  It will probably not fail as is because `size_t` and pointers usually have the same size, but it still isn't really correct.